# How to split a pandas data frame column by index position in values

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame column as follows.

| variable |
| --- |
| m4 |
| m410 |
| f1115 |

I would like to separate it into 2 columns where the value of the first column is the first character of the value and the second column is the rest.

| col1. | col2. |
| --- | --- |
| m | 4 |
| m | 410 |
| f | 1115 |

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the `(\D+)(\d+)` regex (non digits followed by digits):

```
df[['co1', 'col2']] = df['variable'].str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)')

# of if you want to remove "variable":
df[['co1', 'col2']] = df.pop('variable').str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)')
```

or for a **new** DataFrame:

```
out = df['variable'].str.extract('(?P<col1>\D+)(?P<col2>\d+)')
```